# React Context API trouble with displaying specific items details page

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am new to React and am trying to understand the Context api.  Right now I have a component that displays a list of items.  I also have a component that displays the detailed info about that item.  What I am trying to do is when I click on a certain item the display component show the info for that item.  Here is my current code.  I am currently getting an error that is state is not defined in my Product.js file.

```
PRODUCTS.JS
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { MyProvider, MyContext } from "./Context";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Products extends Component {

  render() {
    const { id } = this.state.products
    return (
      <div className="products-list">
        <div className="showcase">
          <MyContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                {context.state.products.map(item => {
                  return (
                    <Link to="/ProductOverview" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}>
                    <div onClick={() => context.productDetail(id)} className="showcase-card" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.bgUrl})`}}>
                      <article key={item.id}>
                        <h6>{item.info}</h6>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                    </Link>
                      );
                  })}
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </MyContext.Consumer>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Products;


CONTEXT.JS
import React, {Component } from 'react';


export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      {
        info: "Toy Car",
        id: '0001'
      },
      {
        info: "Toy Truck",
        id: '0002'
      },
      {
        info: "Toy Plane",
        id: '0003'
      },
      {
        info: "Toy Boat",
        id: '0004'
      }
    ]
  };

  getItem = id => {
    const products = this.state.products.find(item => item.id === id);
    return products;
  };

  productDetail = id => {
    const products = this.getItem();
    this.setState(() => {
      return { products };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{
          state: this.state,
        productDetail: this.productDetail}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}


PRODUCTOVERVIEW.JS

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { MyProvider, MyContext } from "./Context";


class ProductOverview extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
          const {id, info} = context;
        return (
          <h1>{info}</h1>
        )
        }}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
};

export default ProductOverview;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a state for it to be defined and used.
in the begining of your component, specify the state:

```
class Products extends Component {
state = {
   yourState:6
}
render() {
```

Comment: I dont understand why I would need to specify state at the beginning, isnt MyContext.Consumer bringing in the state?

Answer (score 0):

```
const { id } = this.state.products
```

there is no state in your Products component. in order to reach the data in the context store you gotta use arrow function inside your Consumer.

So idea behind context api is, you store your state inside the context object and this object comes with 2 components. PROVIDER and CONSUMER.

Provider:Provider will provide all the information for the app. We are gonna set up provider on top of our app like so:

index.js

```
import { MyProvider } from "./Context";
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </MyProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root"));
```

Consumer: is gonna use the info provided by the provider. We can grab the info wherever we are in our application.

so this is what you are returning  from the Provider.

```
value={{
          state: this.state,
        productDetail: this.productDetail}}
```

value prop is an object. this is how you should access in your components:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
        //context is the object that is returned by the Provider
        //inside state you have products array and you need to choose one of those elements inside the array. lets say you wanna select the first element which is the 0 index.

          const {id, info} = context.state.products[0];
        return (
          <h1>{info}</h1>
        )
        }}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: This line ```<div onClick={() => context.productDetail(id)}``` is returning an error of id is not defined

Comment: i edited the comment. this should work but I feel like you wanna render the products. what exactly do wanna do? i

Comment: Basically when I click on the product in Product.js the link takes me to ProductOverview.js. I want ProductOverview to show the information of the product I clicked on.

Comment: so in products page, you wanna map all the products. so you need to create Product or as ProductDetails component. if you update your question clearly, I ll edit the answer